# Imparfait and passé composé

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, santé-et-médecine

I'm struggling to choose between the *imparfait* and the *passé composé* for a sentence like "I  had a grandfather who passed away because his surgery was a failure".

I know we're supposed to use *imparfait* for continuous actions in the past and for descriptions in the past but I don't know if saying his surgery was a failure is a description. So my attempt is:

> J'ai eu un grand-père qui est décédé parce que sa chirurgie était un échec.

Comment: Imparfait with être here is not about continuous action but a continuous state or condition. He was your grandfather throughout your life (an ongoing situation) until he passed away.  So, j'avais is more commons when speaking here but PC is not bad French. However, sa chirugie a échoué is what I'd say.

Comment: typo correction: more common, no s.

Comment: *J'ai un grand-père qui est mort à la suite d'une opération qui a échoué.* "*Décédé*" is rarely used outside paperworks, forms and tables and we never say *sa chirurgie* for *his surgery* (anglicism).

Comment: Rectification: almost never say.

Comment: Moi et mes amis se sont réunis pour parler de nos familles respectives. *Moi, je leur ai dit que j'avais un grand-père qui est mort* etc. Je ne vois pas comment on peut dire qu'on a un grand-père si le pauvre est déjà dans sa tombe, pour ainsi dire.

Comment: In English or French, I would not use the present to discuss having had a grand-father who was now dead.

Comment: @Lambie Tenses do not necessarily work the same way in French and English. That's a well known fact.

Comment: The fact is that English simple past in a person's speech **can be translated** into passé composé OR imparfait, depending on many factors. However, English simple past does not translate into the present tense in French when the speaker is referring to the past.

Comment: @Lambie The last part of the sentence is referring to the past and is using *passé composé* (*qui est mort*). The first part of the sentence isn't restricted to the past but states a fact that is still true (*j'ai un grand-père*) so the present is the most idiomatic choice in French. Google: "j'avais un grand-père qui est mort" 0 hits, "j'ai eu un grand-père qui est mort" 1 hit, "j'ai un grand-père qui est mort" 26 hits.

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to LPH, I don't see a problem with "J'ai un grand-père qui..."

Here are a couple of examples taken from a Google Books search:

- *Je suis assez fier d'avoir un grand-père qui est mort de la goutte.*
- *Il paraît que c'est très grave d'avoir un grand-père qui montait au cocotier.*

I think this kind of construction, "Il y a un X qui..." or "J'ai un X qui...", tends to be much more common in speech than using "Un X..." or "Un de mes X..." as the subject of a sentence. In formal writing, there's a tendency to prefer the second construction, but I don't think it makes the first kind wrong.

With that being said, I think francophones are more likely to say "J'ai un grand-père qui est décédé..." than "J'ai eu un grand-père qui est décédé...".

In your sentence, many speakers might prefer "sa chirurgie avait été un échec" to match the timeline, but I think "a été un échec" or "était un échec" are absolutely things you might hear. Of these two, the passé composé seems the more likely because you're talking about the result of the surgery, but I also think "était" is possible.

Edit: There are some comments to the effect that *opération* is required instead of *chirurgie*. A Google search yielded the following examples taken from websites of hospitals and clinics in France and Canada:

- *La nourriture : avoir de bonnes habitudes alimentaires favorise les résultats de votre chirurgie.*
- *Vous n'avez pas besoin de passer la nuit à la clinique avant ou après votre chirurgie.*
- *En fonction de votre chirurgie, votre anesthésiste pourra vous...*
- *L'Hôpital d'Ottawa lance aujourd'hui une nouvelle section dans son site Web qui aidera les patients à se préparer pour leur chirurgie.*

Edit: Here are some additional examples from Google Books.

- *Toutefois, il est clair qu'**une chirurgie réussie** commence par une bonne indication.*
- *Les avantages potentiels de la PRG sont une recherche facilitée des parathyroïdes agrandies, la réduction du temps opératoire, l'identification du tissu parathyroïdien ectopique, une baisse de l'utilisation d'examen extemporané et de l'ioPTH, et la vérification **d'une chirurgie réussie**.*
- *Même si certains enfants semblent faire appel à d'énormes capacités adaptatives, force nous est de constater qu'après **une chirurgie réussie**, les relations...*
- ***Une chirurgie réussie** améliore la qualité de vie des patients.*

Edit: I found [this Google Ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=subi%20une%20op%C3%A9ration%2C%20subi%20une%20chirurgie&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csubi%20une%20op%C3%A9ration%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csubi%20une%20chirurgie%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csubi%20une%20op%C3%A9ration%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csubi%20une%20chirurgie%3B%2Cc0) revealing. The use of *chirurgie* to mean *opération* seems to have begun in the 1960s, and it appears that, as of 2019, *chirurgie* had become about one-sixth as common as *opération*. This may be a case where reference works have failed to catch up with usage. Based on the views jlliagre has expressed, it is fair to assume that some people find this usage odd or unacceptable, even though it may not be infrequent.

Comment: @Lambie I actually think the present tense *j'ai un grand-père* is more likely here, despite the fact that the grandfather may be long gone.

Comment: La chirurgie est une branche de la médecine. Je n'ai jamais entendu quelqu'un dire *sa chirurgie a réussi/échoué* et Google non plus: *Aucun résultat trouvé pour "sa chirurgie a échoué"* alors que *son opération a échoué* remonte quantité de résultats donc je persiste à penser qu'il s'agit d'un anglicisme, même si des apparitions sporadiques sont possibles en France. Au Québec, cette métonymie semble plus acceptée, je le concède mais on peut constater qu'on ne dit à ma connaissance jamais *sa pédiatrie a échoué, sa gynécologie a échoué, sa psychiatrie a échoué, son ophtalmologie a échoué etc.*

Comment: OQLF: (Vocabulaire de la chirurgie) *Bien que la métonymie soit un procédé de création lexicale fréquent en français, on ne peut néanmoins écarter une possible influence de l'anglais dans ce cas-ci.*

Comment: @jillagre Je retiens de cet article que, bien que l'anglais ait pu influencer l'usage dans ce cas, "Pour désigner le présent concept, le terme chirurgie est un emploi métonymique acceptable".

Comment: Oui, j'ai été trop affirmatif en écrivant *jamais*. C'est considéré comme acceptable par l'OQLF mais je continue à considérer que c'est un anglicisme en France.

Comment: Sur Google Books, j'ai trouvé quatre exemples de "son opération a échoué" en rapport avec une opération chirurgicale. La plupart des résutats ont trait à d'autres sortes d'opérations. Il me semble tout à fait plausible qu'*opération* soit beaucoup plus fréquent que *chirurgie* dans ce contexte, mais je ne vois pas de raison de conclure que *chirurgie* soit rare, compte tenu des nombreuses occurrences de *chirurgie* comme synonyme d'*opération* dans d'autres contextes.

Comment: Ok, l'idiomaticité d'une expression peut être une notion subjective et donc discutable. L'essentiel est d'être compris et, selon ce critère, ça passe.

Comment: Je note quand même qu'il ne semble qu'aucun dictionnaire édité en France ne mentionne ce sens de *chirurgie* alors qu'il est bien présent pour *surgery* dans tous les dictionnaires anglais que j'ai consultés. C'est aussi le cas pour le wiktionnaire et wikipédia. Je reste persuadé qu'en France, dans un contexte scolaire ou universitaire, la traduction de *surgery* par *chirurgie* quand le sens original est celui d'intervention chirurgicale, d'opération, serait sanctionnée par les correcteurs. Ce ne serait bien sûr pas le cas au Québec.

Comment: Tout le monde cite Google Books ici. A moins de trouver des dialogues dans ces livres, je vois mal comment ils peuvent est une source infos. fiable au sujet du **français parlé**.

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, au Québec on dit indifféremment _chirurgie_ et _opération_, je dirais même que la première variante est plus courante. Même mon vét qui vient de France le dit. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a couple of ways to say "I had a grandfather who passed away because his surgery was a failure" in French:

> *J'**ai** un grand-père qui **est** mort à la suite d'une opération<sup>1</sup> qui a échoué.*

> *Mon grand-père (maternel/paternel) est mort après une opération qui a échoué.*

*J'ai eu un grand-père...* (*passé composé*) is not inconceivable but much less natural than the present tense.

Similarly, *j'avais un grand-père...* (*imparfait*) is unlikely to be used because being your grand-father is a status that expires not with his death but with you own death so you would say:

> *J'**ai** un grand-père qui est mort d'un arrêt du cœur. Mon grand-père **avait** aussi un grand-père qui **est**/**était** mort d'un arrêt du cœur*

English uses *to pass away* to politely avoid *to die*. We have similar expressions in French like *nous a quitté*, *a perdu la vie* and *s'est éteint*.

Should you want a formal sentence, you might say :

> *Mon grand-père nous a quitté après une opération qui a échoué.*

I wouldn't use *est décédé* here because while it also avoids using *mourir*, *décéder* is lacking empathy and therefore more suitable for paperworks, forms or tables.

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>If you use *chirurgie* for "surgery" when the latter means  the work done by a surgeon and not the branch of medicine related to such works, you'll be understood but raise eyebrows in France, where this usage is not listed in dictionaries and very rare (I personally never heard it.) I'm pretty sure that if you use that translation in an assignment, it would considered a mistake by the corrector. This wouldn't be the case in Québec where this acceptation is documented ([OQLF](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8871282)). In France, the usual translations are *opération* and *intervention* with *chirurgicale* appended when the context doesn't make it implicit.</sub>

Comment: I had a grandfather is definitely not: j'ai un grand-père.

Comment: @Lambie The single and complete sentence "**I had** a grandfather" translates to ***j'ai eu** un grand-père* and "**I had** a funny grandfather" translates to ***j'avais** un grand-père rigolo*, however, in "I had a grandfather **who passed away because sth**", the first part translates to ***J'ai** un grand-père qui...* in idiomatic French. Translating it to ***J'avais** un grand-père qui...* makes little sense unless you repudiate him, he resurrected or something.

Answer (score -1):

- J'ai eu un grand-père qui est décédé parce que sa chirurgie était un échec.

In French, you wouldn't say "avoir un grand-père"; it is not idiomatic and it goes against a certain logic of the verb/context. One  would normally say "mon grand-père" or, if careful, "mon grand-père paternel" or "mon grand-père maternel". For the sake of using a verb, let's say that this man is not known to the the person asking about him; we can then write this;

- C'était mon grand-père et il est décédé parce que son opération chirurgicale a été un échec.

You use the "imparfait" for "être" (c'était) because the state of being perdured in the past, and you use the "passé composé" for the other two verbs because those actions are *one time actions* in the past ([Lingolia](https://francais.lingolia.com/en/grammar/tenses/le-passe-compose)).

Note: You can't say "chirurgie" to mean "opération chirurgicale" (which you abbreviate to "opération" when there is no possible confusion).

Comment: J'avais une amie à la fac qui, par la suite, etc.  Alors, pourquoi pas: J'avais un  grand-père qui. [etc.]?

Comment: @Lambie Ce n'est pas usuel dans ce contexte; d'abord, on n'a que deux grands-pères, et ce n'est pas assez pour dire "j'avais un grand-père". Ensuite, le contexte où on place le personnage dans l'ensemble de tous les grands-pères, n'est pas celui de la phrase discutée. (ex. : Nos grands-pères étaient des hommes farouches, il fallait peu pour les irriter; personnellement, j'ai eu des grands-parents  qui n'étaient pas du tout irascibles.).  C'est la même chose pour « femme » (dans le sens de « épouse ») ou « épouse ». Étant donné que l'on peut en avoir au moins jusqu'à  (1/2)

Comment: @Lambie huit au cours d'une vie, il y a un cas pour « j'ai eu une épouse … », et on sera enclin à croire que l'homme en question aura eu plusieurs épouses , mais d'habitude on dira « mon épouse », « ma femme ». (2/2)

Comment: Mais non, si on parle à un groupe de personnes qui décrivent les membres de leurs familles, on peut très bien imaginer des phrases comme: Moi, j'avais un grand-père qui etc.

Comment: @Lambie Eh bien dans ce cas on retombe dans le contexte où on place cet homme dans l'ensemble de tous les grands-pères ; dans ce cas c'est idiomatique. Donc, je ne pense pas être dans le faux.

Comment: Tu dis bien:  In French, you wouldn't say "avoir un grand-père"; it is not idiomatic and it goes against a certain logic of the verb/context. Ça, c'est faux.

Comment: @Lambie It does not apply generally, it is understood to be limited to the context of the OP's sentence.